# Calculation of the Bowling Game score

Tags: c#

I am new in developer role, and I have my code which I would like to simplify or make it better.
And wondering if someone can do a quick check.

The code calculates the Score of the Bowling game, which is input as a string of the whole game (ex. as following: "X|7/|9-|x|-8|8/|-6|x|X|X||81").

Program.cs

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("#=======================#");
        Console.WriteLine("# Welcome to Ten-Pin Bowling! #");
        Console.WriteLine("#=======================#");

        var game = new TenPinGame("X|7/|9-|x|-8|8/|-6|x|X|X||81");
        Console.WriteLine("Game: {0}", input);
        Console.WriteLine("Score: " + game.Score());
        Console.WriteLine("#=====#");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for playing with us!");
        Console.WriteLine("Have a nice day!");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

TenPinGame.cs

```
public class TenPinGame : IGame
{
    public const int MaxFrameNumber = 10;
    public const int StartingPinsNumber = 10;
    public List<Frame> Frames { get; } = new List<Frame>();

    private string[] framesStringArray;
    public static string bonusSubsctring;


    public TenPinGame (string gameInput)
    {
        string framesSubstring = ParseGame(gameInput);
        framesStringArray = Utilities.SplitFramesString(framesSubstring, MaxFrameNumber);
        FrameRepository.ProcessFrameString(framesStringArray, Frames, MaxFrameNumber, StartingPinsNumber);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Splitting input string into 2 parts: Frames and Bonus throws
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameInput"></param>
    internal string ParseGame(string gameInput)
    {
        string framesSubstring = "";

        if (gameInput.Contains("||"))
        {
            int index = gameInput.IndexOf("||");
            framesSubstring = gameInput.Substring(0, index);
            bonusSubsctring = gameInput.Substring(index + 2);
        }
        return framesSubstring;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate the Total score for the whole game/line.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int Score()
    {
        int score = 0;
        foreach (var frame in Frames)
        {
            int frameIndex = Frames.IndexOf(frame);
            if (!frame.IsLastFrame && frame.IsStrike)
            {
                if (Frames[frameIndex + 1].Throws.Count == 1)
                    score += 10 + Frames[frameIndex + 1].Throws[0] + Frames[frameIndex + 2].Throws[0];
                else if (Frames[frameIndex + 1].Throws.Count == 2 || Frames[frameIndex + 1].Throws.Count == 3)
                    score += 10 + Frames[frameIndex + 1].Throws[0] + Frames[frameIndex + 1].Throws[1];
                //else
                //    throw new ArgumentException($"The next frame has invalid throws count {Frames[frameIndex + 1].Throws.Count}.");
            }
            else if (!frame.IsLastFrame && frame.IsSpare)
            {
                score += 10 + Frames[frameIndex + 1].Throws[0];
            }
            else if (frame.IsLastFrame && frame.IsStrike)
            {
                score += 10 + Frames[frameIndex].Throws[1] + Frames[frameIndex].Throws[2];
            }
            else if (frame.IsLastFrame && frame.IsSpare)
            {
                score += 10 + Frames[frameIndex].Throws[1];
            }
            else
            {
                score += frame.Throws[0] + frame.Throws[1];
            }
        }

        return score;
    }

}
```

Frame.cs

```
public class Frame
{
    public List<int> Throws = new List<int>();
    public int KnokcedDownPinsCount { get; set; }
    public bool IsStrike { get; set; }
    public bool IsSpare { get; set; }
    public bool IsLastFrame { get; set; }
    public bool IsBonusAllowed { get; set; }
    public bool IsFrameOver { get; set; }



    public Frame(bool isLastFrame = false)
    {
        this.IsLastFrame = isLastFrame;
    }


    public void ValidateEachThrow ()
    {
        if (TenPinGame.StartingPinsNumber == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Sorry, no pins are left standing.");
        }
        if (KnokcedDownPinsCount < 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Sorry, the # of knocked down pins {KnokcedDownPinsCount} is out of range.");
        }
        else if (KnokcedDownPinsCount > TenPinGame.StartingPinsNumber)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Sorry, the # of knocked down pins {KnokcedDownPinsCount} is is more than {TenPinGame.StartingPinsNumber} still standing pins.");
        }
    }

}
```

Utilities.cs

```
public class Utilities
{


    /// <summary>
    /// Split each frame into a separate string in the string array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="framesString"></param>
    public static string[] SplitFramesString(string framesString, int maxFrameNumber)
    {
        string[] framesStringArray = Array.Empty<string>();
        if (framesString.Contains("|"))
        {
            framesStringArray = framesString.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (framesStringArray.Length > maxFrameNumber)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Sorry, you have {framesStringArray.Length} frames, " +
                    $"which is higher than Max number of {maxFrameNumber} frames allowed for this game.");
            }
        }
        return framesStringArray;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Process each charcters in the given frame and set corresponding frame properties accordingly. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="characterInString"></param>
    /// <param name="Frames"></param>
    /// <param name="stratingPinsNumber"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int ProcessCharArray(char characterInString, Frame Frames, int stratingPinsNumber)
    {
        int pinsCount = 0;

        if (characterInString >= '0' && characterInString <= '9')
        {
            Frames.Throws.Add((int)char.GetNumericValue(characterInString));
            pinsCount = int.Parse(characterInString.ToString());
        }
        else if (characterInString.ToString().ToUpperInvariant() == "X")
        {
            Frames.IsStrike = true;
            Frames.IsFrameOver = true;
            Frames.Throws.Add(10);
            pinsCount = 10;
        }
        else if (characterInString.ToString().ToUpperInvariant() == "/")
        {
            Frames.IsSpare = true;
            Frames.IsFrameOver = true;
            Frames.Throws.Add(stratingPinsNumber - Frames.Throws[0]);
            pinsCount = 10;
        }
        else if (characterInString.ToString().ToUpperInvariant() == "-")
        {
            Frames.Throws.Add(0);
            pinsCount += 0;
        }
        else if (characterInString.ToString().ToUpperInvariant() == "/" && Frames.IsLastFrame && Frames.IsBonusAllowed)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The Spare cannot be set on the Bonus Throws, please check.");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid argument '{characterInString}' was detected in the provided input, please check.");
        }

        return pinsCount;
    }
}
```

FrameRepository.cs

```
public class FrameRepository
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Process each frame-string in the frames string array, to determine the pins count for each frame
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="framesList"></param>
    public static void ProcessFrameString(string[] framesList, List<Frame> Frames, int MaxFrameNumber, int StartingPinsNumber)
    {
        foreach (var frame in framesList)
        {
            if (!Frames.Any() || Frames.Last().IsFrameOver)
            {
                var isLastFrame = Frames.Count == MaxFrameNumber - 1;
                Frames.Add(new Frame(isLastFrame));
            }

            char[] frameCharArr = frame.ToCharArray();
            foreach (char c in frameCharArr)
            {
                Frames.Last().KnokcedDownPinsCount = Utilities.ProcessCharArray(c, Frames.Last(), StartingPinsNumber);

                if (!Frames.Last().IsLastFrame && Frames.Last().Throws.Count == 2)
                {
                    Frames.Last().IsFrameOver = true;
                }
            }

            if (Frames.Count == MaxFrameNumber)
            {
                Frames.Last().IsLastFrame = true;
                char[] bonusCharArr = TenPinGame.bonusSubsctring.ToCharArray();
                if (Frames.Last().IsStrike)
                {
                    if (bonusCharArr.Length > 2)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException($"The number of bonus throws {bonusCharArr.Length}, is over allowed for the Last Strike. Please check.");
                    }
                    Frames.Last().IsBonusAllowed = true;
                    foreach (char c in bonusCharArr)
                    {
                        Frames.Last().KnokcedDownPinsCount = Utilities.ProcessCharArray(c, Frames.Last(), StartingPinsNumber);
                    }
                }
                else if (Frames.Last().IsSpare)
                {
                    if (bonusCharArr.Length != 1)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException($"The number of bonus throws {bonusCharArr.Length}, is over allowed for the Last Spare. Please check.");
                    }
                    Frames.Last().IsBonusAllowed = true;
                    Frames.Last().KnokcedDownPinsCount = Utilities.ProcessCharArray(bonusCharArr[0], Frames.Last(), StartingPinsNumber);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Something to note: you pass the overall game data into TenPinGame as a string, which you then parse. It would make sense to parse this data first, then instantiate the Game object.

Imagine if you had to add a new feature, which allowed users to input scores from a User Interface. You would then have two "access points", your *TenPinGame* class should reflect this.

From what I can see, there are three functions relating to input parsing: *SplitFramesString*, *ProcessCharArray* and *ParseGame*. It would make sense to move these three functions into a separate *GameInputParser*, like so:

```
public class GameInputParser
{
    public static string[] SplitFramesString(string framesString, int maxFrameNumber) { /*code*/ }

    public static int ProcessCharArray(char characterInString, Frame Frames, int stratingPinsNumber) { /*code*/ }

    internal string ParseGame(string gameInput) { /*code*/ }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From a functional perspective, you could change your `ProcessCharArray` to stop allocating unneeded memory on the heap by using this. Being that a `char` is derivative of `ValueType`. The memory will be allocated on the stack within your defined scope and will keep the GC from cleaning up the mess that's created with `characterInString.ToString().ToUpperInvariant() == "X"`.

```
public static int ProcessCharArray(char characterInString, Frame Frames, int 
stratingPinsNumber)
{
    int pinsCount = 0;

if (char.IsDigit(characterInString))
{
    Frames.Throws.Add((int)char.GetNumericValue(characterInString));
    pinsCount = int.Parse(characterInString.ToString());
}
else if (char.ToUpperInvariant(characterInString) == 'X')
{
    Frames.IsStrike = true;
    Frames.IsFrameOver = true;
    Frames.Throws.Add(10);
    pinsCount = 10;
}
else if (characterInString == '/')
{
    Frames.IsSpare = true;
    Frames.IsFrameOver = true;
    Frames.Throws.Add(stratingPinsNumber - Frames.Throws[0]);
    pinsCount = 10;
}
else if (characterInString == '-')
{
    Frames.Throws.Add(0);
    pinsCount += 0;
}
else if (characterInString == '/' && Frames.IsLastFrame && Frames.IsBonusAllowed)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("The Spare cannot be set on the Bonus Throws, please check.");
}
else
{
    throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid argument '{characterInString}' was detected in the provided input, please check.");
}

    return pinsCount;
}
```

here is an alternative approach for the logic in your method as well. :)

```
if (char.IsDigit(characterInString))
{
    Frames.Throws.Add((int)char.GetNumericValue(characterInString));
    var pinsCount = int.Parse(characterInString.ToString());
    return pinsCount;
}

switch(char.ToUpperInvariant(characterInString))
{
    case 'X':
        Frames.IsStrike = true;
        Frames.IsFrameOver = true;
        Frames.Throws.Add(10);
        return 10;
    case '-':
        Frames.Throws.Add(0);
        return 0;
    case '/':
        if(Frames.IsLastFrame && Frames.IsBonusAllowed)
            throw new ArgumentException("The Spare cannot be set on the Bonus Throws, please check.");

        Frames.IsSpare = true;
        Frames.IsFrameOver = true;
        Frames.Throws.Add(stratingPinsNumber - Frames.Throws[0]);
        return 10;
    default :  throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid argument '{characterInString}' was detected in the provided input, please check.");      
}
```